# Replacing html button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've done some research regarding on how to replace/change the original html button to another. But neither the ways are working.

Here are my codes:

Javascript:

```
var editBtn = "editBtn" + id; //in order to get the id of the edit button
var cSave = document.getElementById(editBtn);
cSave.innerHTML = "<td><button id='saveBtn' onclick='saveChange(" + id + ");' >Save</button></td>";
```

The code above is just adding a button inside the existing button.

HTML:

```
<table>
<td>
<%
  out.println("<button id='editBtn" + mc.getId() + "' onclick='editMC(this.id);'>Edit</button>");
%>
</td>
</table>
```

The mc.getId() is a method to get the "id".

The latest approach that I've tried is mentioned below, but it's not working:

```
document.getElementById(editBtn).onclick = function() {saveChange(id)};
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#editBtn").replaceWith("<td><button id='saveBtn' onclick='saveChange(" + mcId + ");' >Save</button></td>");
});
```

Anyhow I can do to change the edit button to save button while onclick() is performed?

Comment: You tagged this question as [tag:jquery], so have you tried to use it?

Comment: `document.getElementById(editBtn)` , IS editBtn Variable ? , if not then  make it `document.getElementById("editBtn")`

Comment: `#editBtn` is not the ID of the button, it's calling a function that adds  something to the ID.

Comment: @user3743562 In your example you're replacing even the `TD` element which is wrong. Take a look at my demo.

Comment: thanks guys, so far the way that Anjum provided works for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the text of the button from Edit to Save using innerHtml. You are actually putting some html inside the button element. Try

```
var cSave = document.getElementById(editBtn);
cSave.innerHTML = "Save";
cSave.onclick = function() {saveChange(id)};
```

Comment: Anjum, the text has changed but the function () {saveChange(id)} does not work upon clicking it again.

Comment: cSave.setAttribute("onclick","javascript:saveChange(id);");

Comment: Oh my bad, was posting to a wrong .jsp, anyhow thanks, it work :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the ID in quotes (unless it's a variable name):

```
document.getElementById("editBtn");
```

in jQuery it would be between this lines:

```
var mcId = 'bla';

function saveChange(){
  alert( mcId );
}


$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand


   $("#editBtn").click(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith("<button id='saveBtn'>Save</button>");
   });

  // Than, for your dynamically generated element use:

  $('#parent').on('click', "#saveBtn", function(){
     saveChange( mcId );
  });

});
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kewat/4/edit)**

note that I used for static element reference a non-dynamic `#parent`. You should do the same (to prevent bonding to `$(document)` as it's quite expensive to listen to events all the way up the DOM).

[jQuery .on() with event delegation for dynamically generated elements](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)